# Node is showing offline in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

After creating node, it is showing offline
Below are setting screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGkZT.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJI82.png)

Error in Logs:

```
SSHLauncher{host='172.31.45.187', port=22, credentialsId='cp1', jvmOptions='', javaPath='', prefixStartSlaveCmd='', suffixStartSlaveCmd='', launchTimeoutSeconds=60, maxNumRetries=10, retryWaitTime=15, sshHostKeyVerificationStrategy=hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.NonVerifyingKeyVerificationStrategy, tcpNoDelay=true, trackCredentials=true}
[09/11/23 09:22:57] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to 172.31.45.187:22.
[09/11/23 09:22:57] [SSH] WARNING: SSH Host Keys are not being verified. Man-in-the-middle attacks may be possible against this connection.
ERROR: Server rejected the 1 private key(s) for cp1 (credentialId:cp1/method:publickey)
[09/11/23 09:22:57] [SSH] Authentication failed.
Authentication failed.
[09/11/23 09:22:57] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[09/11/23 09:22:57] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

In credentials using SSH username with private key.
Enter red private key as content of pem file.